# Looking for a specific CMS

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for an application (web application, like WordPress) that you put your code into (CSS, HTML, etc.) and do something like "define variables" in the custom code that your clients can come back later and change without having to see any code.

Is there anything like this out there? Even close?

Comment: You need to be more specific. You're pretty much describing the basic premise behind CMS applications as a whole. You set up the template, and all your client generally ever sees is some forms to fill out asking for titles, content, etc. If your client is "seeing code" in WordPress(what does that mean to you?) then you've probably just given them too much access and need to downgrade their permissions.

Comment: I think what they are getting at is that with most CMS you need to define templates, and they need something a little more ad hoc because the client maybe only updates a handful of small bits of content on a mainly static site.

Comment: I have my own solution which I use on websites I make for my clients; it allows you to edit only what needs to be editable, and keeps all of the HTML/CSS completely out of it.  If you want to know more, click my profile & get in touch.

Comment: @Toby: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. S/he didn't say anything about a mostly-static site, but even so, most CMSes, even Wordpress, allow you to create a "mostly" static site if you just choose not to update it. You can still create regular pages and allow the client to change however much or little of it as they want. And no matter what you go with, you'll still need to have a theme or template or some kind of web design done. If you don't want to design it yourself, most CMSes come with default themes.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I assumed that based on the fact they want to define variables for editing instead of chunks of text.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Perch](http://grabaperch.com/) will be perfect for your needs, it does exactly that.